# How to run .reg files when running the msi?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I am trying to understand how my setup.msi inserts registry values when installing it. In Orca editor  I am seeing like this,

[image]

After installing the msi, in the log file I am seeing like this,

```
MSI (s) (A8:B4) [16:27:28:674]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={45667B7F-9DC7-43B7-BE9E-3215ED1B1985},KeyPath=02:\SOFTWARE\myCompany\MySolution\Plugins\MyProduct\ProductCode,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
```

I want to do the reverse engineering of this mechanism, can any one help me to understand this? I want to recreate the same using WIX, so I just tried like below

```
 <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="*">
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Microsoft\MyCompany"
                  Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
              <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="MyApp" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]" KeyPath="yes"/>
              <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Configuration Files" Value="[INSTALLLOCATIONCONFIG]"/>
              <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Configuration Files1" Value="[INSTALLLOCATIONCONFIG1]"/>
            </RegistryKey>
          </Component>
```

When I built the msi and if edit it Orca, I am seeing like below,
[image]

What should I do to get the msi as shown in the previous image?

Comment: I am not able to add images????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSI expresses registry data in the [Registry table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  During the installation, the system determines which features and components are being installed therefore which registry adds, updates and deletes to perform. The actual work is carried out by the [WriteRegistryValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RemoveRegistryValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) actions.

It is not a best practice to "execute a reg file" during an installation because it's out of process and MSI can't manage the changes.   Instead use the [WiX Heat tool](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) to harvest the contents of the registry file into wix xml source for inclusion in your installer.

Comment: I understand that running, say Reg.exe, during MSI processing (via Custom Action) is severely frowned upon for the reason you stated, Windows Installer has no idea what you did. But, would that be a potential suitable "fix" for my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734501/wix-reasonable-way-to-fix-original-version-uninstall-issue-with-new-version-i)?